# Change the color and thickness of the vertical line that separates two subfigures

Tags: subfloats

I am using the following code to insert two subfigures:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\rulesep}{\unskip\ \vrule\ }
  \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
        \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centerlast}
        \begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfigure_1.jpeg}
        \caption[caption]{This is the caption\\Isosurface corresponding to \, $\lambda_{2,m} = -3$.}
        \label{subfig1}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \hfill
        \rulesep
        \begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{subfigure_2.jpeg}
        \caption[caption]{This is the caption\\Isosurface corresponding to \, $\lambda_{2,m} = -3$.}
        \label{subfig2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Figure 1}
        \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

As one can see the command responsible for the insertion of the vertical line is `\rulesep`. I am not able to change the thickness and color of the line. Can someone please help me do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\color`. I also changed slightly the definition of `\rulesep`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centerlast}

\newcommand{\rulesep}{\unskip\hfill{\color{red}\vrule}\hfill\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\caption[caption]{This is the caption\\Isosurface corresponding 
  to $\lambda_{2,m} = -3$.\label{subfig1}}
\end{subfigure}
\rulesep
\begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\caption[caption]{This is the caption\\Isosurface corresponding
  to $\lambda_{2,m} = -3$.\label{subfig2}}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change `\vrule` into `\vrule width 1pt` you get

[image]